# What is the difference between printing System.now() and after using String.valueOf(System.now())

Tags: date

Hi i am not able to understand What is the difference between printing System.now() and after using String.valueOf(System.now()) bcz both giving me different out/put.
Example:

```
System.debug(' date()'+System.now()); getting o/p 2013-08-12 06:26:18
System.debug(' date()'+String.valueOf(System.now())); o/p 2013-08-11 23:26:18
```

Can any one please explain me why i am getting two different date outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.debug(' date()'+String.valueOf(System.now())); o/p 2013-08-11 23:26:18
```

This will be as per local time zone of the user

```
System.debug(' date()'+System.now()); getting o/p 2013-08-12 06:26:18
```

Returns the current date and time in the GMT time zone.

Reference:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Update:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm

SOQL queries in a client application return dateTime field values as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) values. You can use convertTimezone() in a date function to convert dateTime fields to the user's time zone.

Comment: ok i got but how we can access system current time?

Comment: current time in GMT or local of system?

Comment: Kumarthanks like String.valueOf() function DAY_IN_MONTH() also return local time zone day? If yes then how i can convert to GTM?

Comment: String.valueOfGmt(System.now()) Use this function to get value in GMT

Comment: ya but plz help for this DAY_IN_MONTH() this function also returning local time zone not GTM.

Comment: SOQL queries in a client application return dateTime field values as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) values. You can use convertTimezone() in a date function to convert dateTime fields to the user's time zone.I have updated the answer please see